# Using tarfile library with special characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, tarfile

I want to create tarfile with Turkish characters(like "ö") but I get an error. I'm using python 2.7 on Windows 8.1.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tarfile
import os
import sys

foldername = "klasör"

foldername = foldername.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())

tar = tarfile.open(foldername + ".tar.gz", "w:gz", compresslevel=5)
tar.add(foldername)
tar.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "u" before the name like so.

```
foldername = u"klasör"
```

You do not need to encode/decode it, instead leave it as unicode and open like you did.